# jenkins jacoco plugin unit and integration coverage separately

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jacoco-plugin

I am integrating jenkins jacoco plugin in the jenkins pipeline at two different stages, one after the unit tests which produced a jacoco.exec file.

I used the jacoco(params) to attach this with the build.

Right after that, I run my integration tests with coverage, and produced jaccoco-it.exec and used jacoco(params) to attach it to the build.

But my build shows two different coverage charts with the merged coverage reports.

I would like to get the unit test coverage and integration test coverage separately on the build. Is this possible at all? I could not find any documentation related to this use case.

Comment: I have the same problem. It would be also helpful to set the title for each graph.